# How to send a GET or POST request inside another GET or POST

Tags: http, post, get, httprequest, web-frameworks

I have a situation where I need to send a GET request inside another GET request.

```
http://domain.com/data?Message=ItsMyMessage&Photo=http://photodomain.com/photo?FileType=1&type=png
```

This is not working!

So, how should I able to do it?

*edit*: I am working on Django

**edit**:

Working:

```
http://myapple.pagekite.me/photo?friend_from=Surya&amp;friend_to=Sophie&amp;image_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapple.pagekite.me%2F%2Fimg%3FFileName%3Dpic5.png%26Message%3DHi%2520
```

Not working (when I publish to Facebook, its getting converted to below):

```
http://myapple.pagekite.me/photo?friend_from=Surya&amp%3Bfriend_to=Sophie&amp%3Bimage_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapple.pagekite.me%2F%2Fimg%3FFileName%3Dpic5.png%26Message%3DHi%2520
```

Note: In the above two code snippets, **`&amp;`** was converted to **`&amp%3B`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to url encode the secondary parameters. Then decode them in your code and send them off.

```
http://domain.com/data?Message=ItsMyMessage&Photo=http%3A%2F%2Fphotodomain.com%2Fphoto%3FFileType%3D1%26type%3Dpng%0A
```

In pure Python you probably will do something like:

```
import sys
from urllib import urlencode
artist = "Kruder & Dorfmeister"
artist = urlencode({'ArtistSearch':artist})
```

Resulting in:

```
ArtistSearch=Kruder+%26+Dorfmeister
```

Credits to O'reilly
http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/h/476

Maybe Django offers some shortcuts here. But I wouldn't know.

Comment: This is working... but I got one problem with this. Actually this whole thing goes under Facebook Share To Wall action and Facebook is doing little mess. **Its changing `&amp;`** to **`&amp%3B`** and thus the whole GET request is not working when its clicked from Facebook Wall.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this issue??

Comment: &amp; is not url encoded. It is an html entity. You cannot have an & char in your url because the character is reserved to mean "and here comes another parameter". Facebook is doing it right. If you have html character entities like &uuml; in your url, you have to convert them to normal characters before you url encode the stuff.

Comment: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm gives some more dtail about what is allowed and wht not.

Comment: well, the problem is when a user clicks that encoded url, web browser isn't able to recognize **`&amp%3B`** when I changed it back to **`&amp;`** it worked

Comment: simply, my request is not working if the URL is rendered to `&amp%3B` I just don't know why!

Comment: Can you give a complete example url that you try posting?

Comment: please take a look at the question

Comment: Try this one: http://myapple.pagekite.me/photo?friend_from=Surya&friend_to=Sophie&image_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapple.pagekite.me%2Fimg%3FFileName%3Dpic5.png%26Message%3DHi%2520

Comment: Using &amp; to concatenate parameters in the url only works on the goodwill of some browsers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16499/discussion-between-surya-and-kai-mattern)

Comment: Chat is currently not an option, due to working conditions here.

Comment: okay!.. not a problem. actually `&amp;` is working but not `&amp%3B`. I am using Chrome.

Comment: As I told you: using &amp; as parameter divider is not http conform. It only works in chrome, as chrome is more clever than it needs to be. parameter delimiter in http get requests is & not &amp; (which is the html entity for &)

Comment: Actually I am pretty novice. is there any another way?? I never knew. if not, how should I fix it

Comment: Did you try the url with the exchanged parameters that I gave you above?